# Oracle hibernate cfg

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am getting this error when trying to start up my hibernate.  I am a hibernate newbie so was hoping someone could point out the mistake I made with my cfg.  I included the error, hope it is an easy fix, thanks.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

```
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"</property>
    <property name="connection.username">scott</property>
    <property name="connection.password">tiger</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2241)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:230)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:71)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:212)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:71)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:206)
at HibernateContext.setConfiguration(HibernateContext.java:20)
at HibernateContext.addClass(HibernateContext.java:205)
at HibernateContext.addClasses(HibernateContext.java:216)
at main.main(main.java:8)
```

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 89; Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2238)
    ... 11 more

Comment: Well, it tells you the line number where the error is.  This is a XMl syntax error your have, and probably has nothing specific to do with hibernate per-se.  if the listing you show is indeed the entire xml file, then you are missing a <session-factory> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using
`<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>`

As a newbie, you can read entire hibernate documentation at
http://www.hibernate.org/docs

Comment: I think this help because now I am just need to figure out my connection error.

Answer (score 0):

change : `connection.driver_class`

to official :
`hibernate.connection.driver_class`

also read this [article](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

Comment: This changed my error to be can not find the JDBC driver.  However, with the oracle driver it is giving me the can not connect error.

Comment: I don't think your a[[ would be work clearly if you don't change to hibernate.connection.driver_class.